# Surface generated by normals to a surface - what does it mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

A problem asks me to do the following:

> Find the equation of the surface generated by the normals to the surface $x + 2yz + xyz^2 = 0$ at all points on the Z axis.

I don't understand what this means!
Sure, we can compute the normal to the given surface at any point (a line, no doubt) - but how do normals generate another surface, of which the question demands the equation?
Please explain!

Comment: Hopefully there is some other context in your textbook (like an example, or an explanation of terminology) because in isolation the question doesn't make sense.